# Smarty Template includes a file that doesn't exist in filesystem, yet still produces content?

Tags: html, templates, smarty

I have a .tpl that includes another that is responsible for producing a block of code I want to edit. I found out where it was by commenting out the {include...} that produces the content. However, when I hunt for the .tpl file on the filesystem, it does not exist. So where is it really stored?

i.e. {include file="user/content.tpl"}
(not located in filesystem)

Is there  some hard-coded address for this in some other file? Is there a conditional if: if file doesn't exist, use this one instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a file exists is easy:

```
{if file_exists("../path_to_file.xxx")}
   /* DO STUFF */
{/if}
```

The filepath in your include can use either an absolute or relativ path, see more examples here -> http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.include.tpl